# how to insert a lookup field value into salesforce via a rest api when it's not a __c field?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-rest-api

**NOTE: there are a million stackoverflow answers explaining inserting into lookup fields that talk about __c fields.  They are NOT duplicates of this question.**

so I'm trying to insert a value into a lookup field using the rest api.
If the field name looks like blah__c - it's easy - I just insert a {key, value} into blah__r.  I do that all over the place.

but in this case my field is called PlanId.   Trying to insert into PlanId__r just says no such field.  How do I do it for a lookup field that does not end in __c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the insert/upsert by external id trick, right? Because vanilla lookup is absolutely the same, just chuck the 15/18-char id in. `blah__c = '001...', PlanId = '003...'`

For standard lookup field (without `__c`) most of the time the relation will be same thing minus the "Id" part. So try `Plan = {'UniqueKey__c', '123'}` or whatever is your equivalent.

(shameless plug) check my answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274696/799, look at how that insert of Asset references Contact and Product2 even though the [actual fields are ContactId, Product2Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm).

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23507/799 might be helpful too. Or just use Workbench etc to [describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) your object.

There are few standard objects where upsert by external id won't work. You might have hard time adding Tasks to Accounts for example because that `WhatId` field is a mutant, lookup to many tables. Was few years since I tried that though so maybe something changed.

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for.. never occurred to me to just "take off the Id" bit - will give it a go

Comment: Glad I could help. You may have attacked it from wrong angle, yes there aren't many posts about upserting it that way. But don't tell me you've never done `SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity` despite the field name being `AccountId` ;)