# Child to Parent SOQL Query

Tags: salesforce, soql

I need a query between `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem`.

`OpportunityLineItem` has a lookup for Opportunity. Child relationship name is `OpportunityLineItems`. Opportunity Lookup field is called `OpportunityId`.

I'm trying the below query but it doesn't work.

```
select Id,Name,OpportunityId__r.Description from OpportunityLineItem
```

Also tried:

```
select Id,Name,OpportunityLineItems__r.Description from OpportunityLineItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-down

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Description,
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM OpportunityLineItems)
FROM Opportunity
```

Bottom-up

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.Description
FROM OpportunityLineItem
```

Check out the links in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913839/313628 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73877986/313628 too